# How to handle song removal event in jPlayer with jPlayerPlaylist add-on

Tags: jplayer

This is my code:

```
var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, [
        {
            title:"Right Now(Na Na Na)",
            artist:"akon",
            mp3: "http://7xiaao.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/Akon - Right Now(Na Na Na).mp3"
            //oga: "/music/",
            //poster: "images/m0.jpg"
        }
    ], {
        playlistOptions: {
            enableRemoveControls: true,
            autoPlay: false
        },
        swfPath: "/res/plugin/jPlayer/dist/jplayer",
        supplied: "mp3",
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        audioFullScreen: false,
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you need to know how to remove the song or how to handle song removal event?

Comment: how to handle song removal event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jPlayerPlaylist](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/) add-on doesn't seem to provide a way to handle song removal event.

The workaround is to handle click events on `x`  yourself, for example:

```
$('.jp-playlist').on('click', '.jp-playlist-item-remove', function(){
    // Determine song index if necessary
    var index = $(this).parents('li').index('.jp-playlist li');

    // Retrieve song information, if necessary
    var song = myPlaylist.playlist[index];
});
```

Comment: but,how dynamic add to playlist

Comment: You can use `myPlaylist.add()` method to add a song, see [jPlayerPlaylist docs](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/) for more info.

Comment: sorry~,can i add `id="XXX"` to playlist item?

Comment: like this: `<li id="XXX"><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item-remove">×</a></li>`

Comment: This seems to be irrelevant to this question, start a new question and I will try to help.

Comment: i have a another question，please help me~ [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123390/jplayer-how-to-display-buffering-text)